# No system event sounds on 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto a new SSD and most things are working fine. One irritation is no sound for system events, although sound works for iPlayer/YouTube or stand-alone files through e.g. VLC. I am very new to Ubuntu so not sure how to diagnose problems, although I have been messing with computers since the mid seventies.

I have found various threads on the web but none of the solutions seem to work. My sound is via HDMI using a Radeon HD 5400/6300 series card on an HP desktop PC. I have PulseAudio Volume Control installed. Under 'Playback' system sounds are set to 140% and mute is off.

I don't know if this is a clue, but I noticed when I click the desktop speaker symbol and go to 'Sound Settings...' then 'Test Sound' then click the 'Test' buttons (in my case Front Left and Front Right) the initial part of the sound is missing on the first click, but then it works Ok for both buttons. If I leave it for 10s or so then try again, the sound is clipped again. For example the first time I press the 'Front Right' button, all I hear is ".......ight". I suspect this behaviour could be the cause of the problem since system sounds usually tend to be fairly short. Also, in Thunderbird if I click Play to test the new message sound, nothing is heard for the first press but subsequent presses work - until there is another delay.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 2 weeks of trying countless suggestions on various forums I only succeeded in making it worse - losing all sound and the speaker icon off the top bar. Finally, on the point of reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch, I tried

`sudo apt-get install unity`

It didn't appear to do anything, at least according to the terminal response, but as if by magic, all my sound problems were solved. I now get system event sounds without the first bit being cut off, sound from YouTube, audio players etc. (all via HDMI). Hope this helps some other poor desperate soul.